# The getter 'pokemon' was called on null

Tags: android, ios, api, flutter, dart

I am trying to make a pokemon app. But I get this error:

"The getter 'pokemon' was called on null.

Receiver: null

Tried calling: pokemon"

I am using this API url for data "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/master/pokedex.json"

And my Pokemon class is here:

```
class PokeHub {
  List<Pokemon> pokemon;

  PokeHub({this.pokemon});

  PokeHub.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) {
    if (json['pokemon'] != null) {
      pokemon = new List<Pokemon>();
      json['pokemon'].forEach((items) {
        pokemon.add(new Pokemon.fromJson(items));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.pokemon != null) {
      data['pokemon'] = this.pokemon.map((items) => items.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Pokemon {
  int id;
  String num;
  String name;
  String img;
  List<String> type;
  String height;
  String weight;
  String candy;
  int candyCount;
  String egg;
  String spawnChance;
  String avgSpawns;
  String spawnTime;
  List<double> multipliers;
  List<String> weaknesses;
  List<NextEvolution> nextEvolution;

  Pokemon(
      {this.id,
        this.num,
        this.name,
        this.img,
        this.type,
        this.height,
        this.weight,
        this.candy,
        this.candyCount,
        this.egg,
        this.spawnChance,
        this.avgSpawns,
        this.spawnTime,
        this.multipliers,
        this.weaknesses,
        this.nextEvolution});

  Pokemon.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    num = json['num'];
    name = json['name'];
    img = json['img'];
    type = json['type'].cast<String>();
    height = json['height'];
    weight = json['weight'];
    candy = json['candy'];
    candyCount = json['candy_count'];
    egg = json['egg'];
    spawnChance = json['spawn_chance'].toString();
    avgSpawns = json['avg_spawns'].toString();
    spawnTime = json['spawn_time'];
    multipliers = json['multipliers']?.cast<double>();
    weaknesses = json['weaknesses'].cast<String>();
    if (json['next_evolution'] != null) {
      nextEvolution = new List<NextEvolution>();
      json['next_evolution'].forEach((v) {
        nextEvolution.add(new NextEvolution.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['num'] = this.num;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['img'] = this.img;
    data['type'] = this.type;
    data['height'] = this.height;
    data['weight'] = this.weight;
    data['candy'] = this.candy;
    data['candy_count'] = this.candyCount;
    data['egg'] = this.egg;
    data['spawn_chance'] = this.spawnChance;
    data['avg_spawns'] = this.avgSpawns;
    data['spawn_time'] = this.spawnTime;
    data['multipliers'] = this.multipliers;
    data['weaknesses'] = this.weaknesses;
    if (this.nextEvolution != null) {
      data['next_evolution'] =
          this.nextEvolution.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class NextEvolution {
  String num;
  String name;

  NextEvolution({this.num, this.name});

  NextEvolution.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    num = json['num'];
    name = json['name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['num'] = this.num;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    return data;
  }
```

And this is my main.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pokemon_flutter/screens/main_screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Poke App",
      home: MainScreen(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }

}
```

And this is my main_screen.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:pokemon_flutter/models/pokemon.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  var url =
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/master/pokedex.json";
  PokeHub pokeHub;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  void fetchData() async {
    var res = await http.get(url);
    var decodedJson = jsonDecode(res.body);
    pokeHub = PokeHub.fromJson(decodedJson);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Poke App"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
      ),
      body: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: pokeHub.pokemon.map((poke) => Card()).toList(),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
        child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It seems like all things are true thats why I can not recognized the fault. If you have a advice for this situation I'll be appreciated.

Edit: I am new here thats why sometimes my questions could be meanless.But please dont decrease my points. Stackoverflow not gonna accept my questions anymore. Please increase my points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call  pokeHub.pokemon, pokeHub is still null so it can't return any value for pokemon getter.
I see that you are fetching data, but when your widget is built, this data (which is returned asynchronously) hasn't been returned yet. For this case, it will be a good choice using FutureBuilder. Something like this should work:

```
   var res;
    void fetchData()  {
      res = http.get(url).then((value){
        var decodedJson = jsonDecode(res.body);
        pokeHub = PokeHub.fromJson(decodedJson);
      });
      
   }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Poke App"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
      future: res,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData)

        return GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: pokeHub.pokemon.map((poke) => Card()).toList(),
        ),
        drawer: Drawer(),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
          child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
        );
      },
    ),
    );
  }
```

This (kind of) uses the futurebuilder to build the widgets only once the data has been retrieved. More info: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But I solved the problem. I am gonna edit now my question. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

when I finished my code the aplication worked. Here is my new main_screen.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:pokemon_flutter/models/pokemon.dart';
import 'package:pokemon_flutter/screens/pokemon_detail_screen.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  var url =
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/master/pokedex.json";
  PokeHub pokeHub;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }
  var res;
  void fetchData() async {
     res= await http.get(url);
    var decodedJson = jsonDecode(res.body);
    pokeHub = PokeHub.fromJson(decodedJson);
    print(pokeHub.toJson());
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Poke App"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
      ),
      body: pokeHub == null
          ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              children: pokeHub.pokemon
                  .map((poke) => Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: (){
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>PokeDetail(
                              pokemon: poke,
                            )));
                          },
                          child: Hero(
                            tag: poke.img,
                            child: Card(
                              elevation: 3.0,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(
                                    height: 100.0,
                                    width: 100.0,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        image: DecorationImage(
                                            image: NetworkImage(poke.img))),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    poke.name,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ))
                  .toList(),
            ),
      drawer: Drawer(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
        child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I added if else statement and set state. I don't know how I solved this problem but it was solved.
I think this codes are worked:

```
 void fetchData() async {
     res= await http.get(url);
    var decodedJson = jsonDecode(res.body);
    pokeHub = PokeHub.fromJson(decodedJson);
    print(pokeHub.toJson());
    setState(() {});
  }
```

```
body: pokeHub == null
          ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : GridView.count(
```